# How to stop debugging python in vim

Tags: python, vim, python-mode

It is my first time to edit python code in vim equipped with python-mode plugin. After setting breakpoints, I use "\ r" command to run it.Then it keep still after printing '[pymode]code running...'.I try some ways but still can not quit debug.It just have no response no matter what I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According official Debugger commands (from [here](https://github.com/jaredly/vim-debug)):

```
[usage:] dbg command [options]
- quit    :: exit the debugger
- run     :: continue execution until a breakpoint is reached or the program ends
         default shortcut: \r
- stop    :: exit the debugger
- over    :: step over next function call
         default shortcut: \o
- watch   :: execute watch functions
         default shortcut: \w
- up      :: go up the stack
         default shortcut: \u
- here    :: continue execution until the cursor (tmp breakpoint)
         default shortcut: \h
- down    :: go down the stack
         default shortcut: \d
- exit    :: exit the debugger
- eval    :: eval some code
- break   :: set a breakpoint
         default shortcut: \b
- into    :: step into next function call
         default shortcut: \i
- out     :: step out of current function call
         default shortcut: \t
```

Comment: Ok, got it. I just think that the python-mode plugin can act as the debugger and can complete it without extra help.

Comment: Except that he's asking about how to control the debugger from a vim plugin called [python-mode](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode) which allows you to set breakpoints (<leader>b) and run your code from vim (<leader>r) but, not how to control the debugger (where I'm stuck too).

Comment: Yeah.. the debugger gets stuck in my vim too. From what I understand there is no way to send a sigint to VIM.

Answer (score 0):

Use :!python3 %, instead of using :PymodeRun or the default keybinding `<leader>r`. That way you run the code in the shell and can break out of it and use the debugger as expected.